# Convert IP string to a list of unicode character values in hex

Tags: c#, unicode, ip, hex, ip-address

Is there any way to convert an IP address string to a hex string, (including dots), and then return the converted hex value!

`"10.10.10.11"` to `hex(7):31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,30,00,2e,00,31,00,00,00,00,00`

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your question, I understand that you actually want to convert the IP address string to its unicode representation, from which you then want to generate a comma separated list of the underlying bytes (encoded in hex).

This will do the trick:

```
string.Join(",", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("10.10.10.11").Select(x => x.ToString("X2")))
```

Output:

```
31,00,30,00,2E,00,31,00,30,00,2E,00,31,00,30,00,2E,00,31,00,31,00
```

Comment: Extra credit for ignoring the title and figuring out the question.

Comment: I got error ? System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found ! What i must add in reference ?

Comment: You need to add `using System.Linq`!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `System.Net.IPAddress` class, then you should be able to get it as an array of bytes.

```
var address = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.11");
var bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
```